Next14 - Shadcn: Warning "In HTML, <div> cannot be a descendant of <p>. This will cause a hydration error."
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Next14 y utilizo componentes de Shadcn, me da un warning en consola asociado a un componente form proveniente de Shadcn, el warning es el descripto en el título, cuando reviso el código de mi componente Form no existe la disposición un div dentro de un párrafo, este problema podría estar dentro de un componente propio de shadcn pero no he logrado descubrirlo, si alguno le pasó y me puede ayudar super agradecido. Aqui va el código del formulario con sus componentes Shadcn:
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { formSchema } from "./FormAddCar.form";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { useState } from "react";
import { UploadButton } from "@/utils/uploadthing";
import { FormAddCarProps } from "./FormAddCar.type";
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export function FormAddCar(props: FormAddCarProps) {
  const { setOpenDialog } = props;
  const [photoUploaded, setPhotoUploaded] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      cv: "",
      transmission: "",
      people: "",
      photo: "",
      priceDay: "",
      engine: "",
      type: "",
      isPublish: false,
    },
  });

  // 2. Define a submit handler.
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    setOpenDialog(false);
    try {
      await axios.post("/api/car", values);
      toast({
        title: "Car created",
      });
      router.refresh();
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: "Something went wrong !!",
        variant: "destructive",
      });
    }
  };

  const { isValid } = form.formState;

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        <div className="grid gap-6 lg:grid-cols-2">
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="name"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="Camioneta Ford Ranger LTS" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="cv"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Power</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="150 HP" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="transmission"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Transmission</FormLabel>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Select type of car" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="manual">Manual</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="automatic">Automatic</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="triptonic">Triptonic</SelectItem>
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="people"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>People Inside</FormLabel>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Select Number People" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="2">2 Passengers</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="4">4 Passengers</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="5">5 Passengers</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="7">7 Passengers</SelectItem>
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="engine"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Type Engine</FormLabel>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Select Type of Engine" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="gasoil">Gasoline</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="diesel">Diesel</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="electric">Electric</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="hybrid">Hybrid</SelectItem>
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="type"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Type of Car</FormLabel>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Select Type of Car" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="sedan">Sedán</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="suv">SUV</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="coupe">Coupé</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="luxe">De Luxe</SelectItem>
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="priceDay"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Price per Day</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder="50.000 $" type="number" {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="photo"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Car Image</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  {photoUploaded ? (
                    <h3 className="text-sm">Image uploaded!</h3>
                  ) : (
                    <UploadButton
                      className="rounded-lg bg-slate-600/20 text-slate-800 outline-dotted outline-3"
                      {...field}
                      endpoint="photo"
                      onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
                        form.setValue("photo", res?.[0].url);
                        setPhotoUploaded(true);
                      }}
                      onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <Button type="submit" className="w-full mt-5" disabled={!isValid}>
          Create Car
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}


